# Notice: Undefined property: MongoId

Tags: php, mongodb

I am a MongoDB beginner.
I want to parse a mongodb document.
But I get this error:
`Notice: Undefined property: MongoId::$created_at` 
This is a part of my document:

```
{"_id":{"$id":"554351e5fd2897ac42000029"},
"0":{"created_at":"Thu Apr 30 12:25:12 +0000 2015",
"id":5.9375296462128e+17},
"1":{"created_at":"Thu Apr 30 12:25:12 +0000 2015",
"id":5.93277777128e+17}
```

And This my PHP code:

```
$cursor = (object)$collection->findOne( $query );
    $l = 0;
    foreach ($cursor as $twt) {
      $twt = (object) $twt;
        $test[$l] = (object)(
       $twt->created_at
        );
        $l = $l +1; }

     echo json_encode($test);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

```
$cursor =$collection->findOne( $query );
    unset($cursor["_id"]);
    $cursor= (object)$cursor;
$l = 0;
    foreach ($cursor as $twt) {
        $twts = (object) $twt;
        $test[$l] = (object)(
       $twts->created_at
        );
    $l = $l +1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object data structure is a little strange, it looks like you have a "0" and a "1" key. Your createdat property is inside the "0" key. Try to flatten your object so that the `createdat` property is at the top level, the same as _id

Comment: I can't touch my document because it's an API's response using some queries and  i have stored it in a MongoDB

Comment: Maybe try `$twt->{0}->createdat`

Comment: Then you will have to use an array instead of casting to an object and access as `$twt[0]['createdat']`

Comment: I get this error `Cannot use object of type MongoId as array`