# modifying a JSON data

Tags: php, json

I want to modify a JSON data format using PHP.
I have an array like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [0] => Thu Apr 30 12:25:12 +0000 2015 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
     [0] => Wed Apr 15 21:57:05 +0000 2015 ) 
      )
```

I have tried the json_encode($data); but it is coming like this:

```
[{"0":"Thu Apr 30 12:25:12 +0000 2015"},{"0":"Wed Apr 15 21:57:05 +0000   2015"}]
```

But I want this format:

```
["Thu Apr 30 12:25:12 +0000 2015","Wed Apr 15 21:57:05 +0000   2015"]
```

what should i do ?

Comment: why you want like this. it will not going to decode next time.

Comment: you'd need to revamp your structure into an array of strings, instead of objects-of-objects.

Comment: I would go back and revisit how the initial array is created. You obviously thought you were creating a simple array but in fact you have created an array of objects, each with a property of '0'.

Comment: AT first  @RiggsFolly , I have a data that i want to parse it [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492158/notice-undefined-property-mongoid/]and after some coding i get this format of data ($data ), in fact i want to get array of objects to use it to get statistics if there is oter possibility please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function, pass your array as argument

```
function to_array_of_strings($data){
    $result_array = array();
        foreach($data as $key => $object){
            foreach($object as $object_key => $object_value){
               $result_array[] = $object_value;
            }
        }
    return $result_array;
}
```

Comment: with your solution the result is a string, but unfortunately I want an array of objects

Comment: You said you want this ["Thu Apr 30 12:25:12 +0000 2015","Wed Apr 15 21:57:05 +0000   2015"], so this is not an array of object, but array of strings. Tell me if I'm right and I'll change the answer to match what you like.

Comment: Checkout a new  function to_array_of_strings($data), from updated answer.

Comment: Your first solution return a string like this ('["Thu Apr 30......]') not an array

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to alter the structure of the array before calling `json_encode()`.

I am not sure why you have an array of such a structure, you may want to look into how `$data` was created in this format. However, working with what you have:

```
$dates = array();
foreach ($data as $obj) {
    $dates[] = $obj->0;
}
print_r(json_encode($dates));
```

Also, **anant kumar singh** makes a very good point, if you are later deserializing this JSON, it will not produce the same array. So again, you should revisit how this array is serialized and deserialized and ensure they match.

Comment: AT first , I have  a data that i want to parse  it  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492158/notice-undefined-property-mongoid/] and after some coding i get this format of data ($data ), in fact i want to get array of objects to use it to get statistics  if there is oter possibility please advice

Comment: She had tried to `json_encode` her $data, she's got something, but all she wanted is to get something else. She doesn't care of deserialization/decode, she can't get the wanted result - `["Thu Apr 30 12:25:12 +0000 2015","Wed Apr 15 21:57:05 +0000   2015"]` in `json` format. I've downvoted because this answer answers to definitely different question.

Comment: You do realize both our answers achieve the same result. Furthermore, there are multiple comments suggesting to revisit the way the initial structure is made to avoid this problem at its root as all of this code would be unnecessary. Nonetheless, I appreciate you owning your down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this an it works:

```
 $i=0;
    foreach($fin as $key1 => $value){
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
            $dates[$i]= $value2 ;
            $i++;
        }
    }
```